# Why do Jedi die in different ways?

Tags: star-wars, jedi

When Darth Vader killed Obi Wan in Episode IV, he vanished completely into thin air. But when Darth Maul (Phantom Menace) killed Qui Gonn Jinn in Episode I, his corpse just lay there with a big hole in his stomach. Why is that?

Comment: Yoda vanished into nothingness, Palpatine exploded, Anakin just died